# Using NPN transistor for constant output current.

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pcb, rf, led-driver

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSkfoG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above schematic i would like to understated that how LED is getting constant current .

Here we are using following component:

1. NPN transistor Q1 = 2SC614
2. forward voltage of an each LED1, LED2 & LED3 = 3.25
3. D1 & D2 = IN4148

Comment: where did you get the circuit? According to me, the voltage across R2 is about 0.6V, which means the current is ~1A. I don't believe it.

Comment: What **is** the current you aim for?

Comment: 700-1000 mA per LED

Comment: Powered from a 9V battery? Your 3 LEDs need 9.75V.

Comment: You show this being powered from a 9 V battery, but then hidden in a comment to a answer you say *"consider input voltage from 12 to 20 V"*.  What the ...?  -1 for jerking us around, and closing while you figure out what you are really asking.

Comment: "I would like to understated that how LED is getting constant current". It's not constant current. R1 bypasses the transistor and allows up to 1.6A through the LEDs with a 20V supply.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit can't possibly work!

The Voltage across your three LEDs is 3 · 3.25 V = 9.75 V > 9 V supply.

You'll need at least \$9.75 + U_{R2} + U_{CE}\$ as supply voltage, so, realistically, nothing less than 11 V will work.

Comment: Please consider input voltage from 12 to 20 V

Comment: Then change for circuit!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very well dimensioned circuit, as answered already, you cannot power the 3 LEDs in series from 9V.

I have filled in some numbers that I would use to check the functionality of this circuit. I run into trouble at the available base current of the NPN. The collector current will be in the order of 0.5 A, since there is only a maximum of 4.9 mA base current available the NPN would need to have a very high beta.

Possible solutions are to lower the value of R3 or replace Q1 with a Darlington transistor (or two transistors in a Darlington configuration) but then a 3rd diode has to be added in series with D5.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqmvUa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But how does this work?

This circuit tries to keep the current constant by means of **local feedback**. The diodes D4 and D5 provide a sort of "reference" voltage of about 1.2 V. Note how the Base-Emitter of the NPN and R2 are in parallel with this 1.2 V reference. This means that if the voltage across R2 **decreases** the voltage across the Base-Emitter of the NPN **increases**. Let's assume that under proper working conditions (1 A through the LEDs) the voltage across the Base-Emitter of the NPN and the voltage across R2 are each 0.6 V (same as each diode).

Now let's assume that the current is **too small**, then the voltage across R2 will be **less** than 0.6 V but the voltage across the Base-Emitter of the NPN will be a bit **more** than 0.6 V. That opens the NPN a bit further forcing the collector current **to increase**. That is **feedback** in action, the current being too small is compensated for by opening the NPN a bit more.

The same happens if the current is too large, then the voltage across the Base-Emitter of the NPN becomes a bit smaller forcing the NPN to conduct less current.

Comment: Thank you so much i will consider input 12 V, What is the purpose of keeping  R1 resistor in parallel to collector & emitter terminal of transistor.

Comment: The only plausible reason for having R1 I can think of is that it "takes over" some current from the NPN so the NPN will have to dissipate less power so a smaller heatsink can be used. The disadvantage of R1 is that it limits the highest supply voltage, as the supply voltage increases more current will go through R1 and less through the NPN. At some point the NPN's current is zero and there will be no more current regulation.

Comment: thanks understood, also please suggest that at which stage this transistor will fail and if this transistor will fail in that case how will current flows in the LEDs.

Comment: Failure is unpredictable so a design should be such that components do not fail (using them within their maximum ratings is a must). Also **contain** the consequences of any failures. In this circuit that's simple, no more than 1 A must flow so add a 1.5 A fuse in series with this circuit. If more current tries to flow the fuse blows.

Comment: @NSR - If you use the components shown, the transistor will fail by burning out. In addition to being limited in maximum current, a 3904 will not dissipate more than about 1/2 watt, and the transistor in this circuit will dissipate about 1 watt at a 12 volt supply.

Comment: I explicitly removed the "2N3905" text from my schematic as that's not a suitable transistor for 0.5 A. The 2SC614 also isn't really suitable as it is an RF transistor and not designed for this job, the metal can housing isn't convenient for the cooling needed here. A BD237 is probably closer but has a low beta, a TIP122 darlington would probably be my choice.